# Alertdialog doesn't show when within if statement

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm building a small app that scans barcodes and put them in a database (using ZXing library). After the scan is taken, and the barcode doesn't exist in the database I want to show a popup dialog that allows an user to enter the name manually. 
The dialog works perfectly if it's invoked in an onClickListener, however when I try to put it in an 'if' statement within another method (which checks if the scan result is in the database) the dialog doesn't show.

What's strange, I put tags in the beginning of the method and at the end, both of them are shown in the log, but the alertdialog doesn't appear and it gets me back to the main activity without any error...

```
public void popUP (String barcode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "method started");
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            final EditText et = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
            Button bt1 = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Button bt2 = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            final String code = barcode1;

            bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mydb.addNewItem(et.getText().toString(), code);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
            Log.d(TAG,"dialog shown");
              }
```

And here is the method from which I try to inflate the popUP

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    final String barcode = scanResult.getContents();
    if (scanResult != null) {
        if(scanResult.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled Scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "SCANNED");

            int rows = mydb.checkRows(barcode);
            if (rows == -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "popUP should appear");

                popUP(barcode); //INVOKING THE ALERT DIALOG

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "found and attempting adding");
                mydb.addItem(barcode, rows);
            }


        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "oddal zero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    Intent intynt = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intynt);
}
```

Comment: You're unconditionally starting `MainActivity` at the end of `onActivityResult()`, so even if your popup does show, you're not going to see it. Execution doesn't stop when a `Dialog` is shown, if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for the information, that was what I was expecting and it's clear now. Any advice what should I look for in order to have it the way I want?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're wanting to happen, there, but do you actually need the `startActivity()` call at the end of `onActivityResult()`? It looks like you might have that covered in the `Dialog`'s `OnClickListener`s.

Comment: Now that I look again, are you sure you want to start another instance of `MainActivity` from `MainActivity`? Maybe you just want to update something in the current `MainActivity` instead?

Comment: @MikeM.simple return; at the end of the 'if' statement does the job :) thanks!